# https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track kills my Angular application. Why?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, request, tracking

My Angular application infinitely sends a request to the `https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track`. Because of that my app does not work and my browser crashes. What may be the reasons for that?

[image]

It sends a POST request with no body and gets an empty result.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party libraries which could be the cause for that? Maybe you share some code. I would say, at least `package.json`, `angular.json`, and everything else which you think might make sense to share

Comment: I'm guessing you have Application Insights embedded in your app.

Comment: @jessehouwing, yes I do.

Comment: That's sending stuff to that domain.

Comment: Simply keeping track of how long you are in the page.

Comment: @jessehouwing, these calls happen infinitely. They eat up all my RAM (that is more than 10Gb).

Comment: Probably something else is.